# open select option in new tab on submit opening multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the code, below...Trying to open the menu item in a new tab. If I change more than one, anything that I've changed also opens. In other words I want only the selection made to open in new tab on submit.

**JS:**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#dynamic_select').on('change', function() {
            var url = jQuery(this).val(); // get selected value
            if (url) { // require a URL
                jQuery('#select-link').click(function() {
                    window.open(url,'_blank');
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="dynamic_select">
    <option value="" selected>Pick a Website</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.youtube.com">YouTube</option>
    <option value="https://www.gurustop.net">GuruStop.NET</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is closer to this: (Assumming select-link is a button or something that should be clicked somewhere else on the page)

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
    jQuery('#select-link').click(function() {
      if (jQuery('#dynamic_select').val() != '')
      {
          window.open(jQuery('#dynamic_select').val(),'_blank');
      }
    });
</script>
```

```html
<select id="dynamic_select">
    <option value="" selected>Pick a Website</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.youtube.com">YouTube</option>
    <option value="https://www.gurustop.net">GuruStop.NET</option>
</select>
```

Comment: wasn't working for me, but definitely calling that click function before the onchange worked. I added my working code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve with the following:

jQuery

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#select-link').click(function(){
        var selectLink = jQuery( "#dynamic_select option:selected" ).val();
        window.open(
            selectLink,
            '_blank'
        );
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <span class="label-text">Visit Industry Programs:</span>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Go!" id="select-link">
    <select name="dynamic_select" id="dynamic_select">
        <option value="" selected>Select Site</option>
        <option>Select an industry</option>
        <option>Select an industry</option>
        <option>Select an industry</option> 
    </select>
</form>
```